# Sort for Array of Objects with AlphaNumeric

Tags: javascript, sorting, ecmascript-6

I have a array of Object with mixed Alphanumeric. I need to sort the order by size.

```
var data = [
{size: "40 SHORT", avail: true},
{size: "46 LONG", avail: true},
{size: "42 SHORT", avail: true},
{size: "40 REG", avail: true},
{size: "42 LONG", avail: true},
{size: "42 REG", avail: true},
{size: "44 REG", avail: true},
{size: "44 LONG", avail: true},
{size: "46 REG", avail: true},
{size: "48 REG", avail: true},
{size: "44 SHORT", avail: true},
{size: "38 REG", avail: true},
{size: "40 LONG", avail: true},
{size: "48 LONG", avail: true},
{size: "38 SHORT", avail: true}
]
```

I need the output like this.

```
var Output = [
{size: "38 SHORT", avail: true},
{size: "40 SHORT", avail: true},
{size: "42 SHORT", avail: true},
{size: "44 SHORT", avail: true},
{size: "38 REG", avail: true},
{size: "40 REG", avail: true},
{size: "42 REG", avail: true},
{size: "44 REG", avail: true},
{size: "46 REG", avail: true},
{size: "48 REG", avail: true},
{size: "40 LONG", avail: true},
{size: "42 LONG", avail: true},
{size: "44 LONG", avail: true},
{size: "46 LONG", avail: true},
{size: "48 LONG", avail: true}
]
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? SO is not **get code for free site**

Comment: Just copy/paste your title in Google...

Comment: @Franckentien: That isn't a duplicate. It's partially related, but this one has more complex criteria that isn't solved there.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could split the value and take a numerical value for the given size.

```js
var data = [{ size: "40 SHORT", avail: true }, { size: "46 LONG", avail: true }, { size: "42 SHORT", avail: true }, { size: "40 REG", avail: true }, { size: "42 LONG", avail: true }, { size: "42 REG", avail: true }, { size: "44 REG", avail: true }, { size: "44 LONG", avail: true }, { size: "46 REG", avail: true }, { size: "48 REG", avail: true }, { size: "44 SHORT", avail: true }, { size: "38 REG", avail: true }, { size: "40 LONG", avail: true }, { size: "48 LONG", avail: true }, { size: "38 SHORT", avail: true }];

data.sort(function (a, b) {
    function getParts(o) {
        var array = o.size.split(' ');
        return { value: array[0], size: { SHORT: 1, REG: 2, LONG: 3 }[array[1]] };
    }
    
    var aa = getParts(a),
        bb = getParts(b);
        
    return aa.size - bb.size || aa.value - bb.value;
});

console.log(data)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is sort on the string, but as two different properties. So if you're OK with creating a new array of sorting in place, I'd map the array to an array of objects that holds the original and an additional property that holds the result of splitting the string on the space character.

Then all you need to do is first see if the `SHORT/REG/LOG` match, and if so, sort on the number, else sort on the order defined for those words.

```js
var data = [{size: "40 SHORT", avail: true},{size: "46 LONG", avail: true},{size: "42 SHORT", avail: true},{size: "40 REG", avail: true},{size: "42 LONG", avail: true},{size: "42 REG", avail: true},{size: "44 REG", avail: true},{size: "44 LONG", avail: true},{size: "46 REG", avail: true},{size: "48 REG", avail: true},{size: "44 SHORT", avail: true},{size: "38 REG", avail: true},{size: "40 LONG", avail: true},{size: "48 LONG", avail: true},{size: "38 SHORT", avail: true}];

data = data
  .map(o => ({orig: o, p: o.size.split(' ')}))
  .sort((a, b) => 
    a.p[1] === b.p[1] ? a.p[0] - b.p[0] :
    a.p[1] === "SHORT" || (a.p[1] === "REG" && b.p[1] === "LONG") ? -1 :
    1)
  .map(o => o.orig);

console.log(data);
```

You can do an in-place sort as well. We would just need to copy the result into the original array.

Either way, the benefit here is that we're not doing string splitting and object creation on every iteration inside the `.sort()` callback, which would   be unnecessarily expensive in computation and memory consumption.

---

This one is even a little cleaner and faster. It takes advantage of the inherent reverse alphabetical order of the words. It uses the negated character code of the first letter of each word in the sort, so it's entirely numeric sorting.

```js
var data = [{size: "40 SHORT", avail: true},{size: "46 LONG", avail: true},{size: "42 SHORT", avail: true},{size: "40 REG", avail: true},{size: "42 LONG", avail: true},{size: "42 REG", avail: true},{size: "44 REG", avail: true},{size: "44 LONG", avail: true},{size: "46 REG", avail: true},{size: "48 REG", avail: true},{size: "44 SHORT", avail: true},{size: "38 REG", avail: true},{size: "40 LONG", avail: true},{size: "48 LONG", avail: true},{size: "38 SHORT", avail: true}];

data = data
  .map(o => {
    let [n,t]=o.size.split(' ');
    return {orig:o, n:+n, t:-t.charCodeAt()}
  })
  .sort((a, b) => a.t - b.t || a.n - b.n)
  .map(o => o.orig);

console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my try. It's not generic, but the idea is to separate literal part of "size" from numeric part of "size" and make a sequential comparison.

```
function compare(a, b) {
  // obvious equality case, just to skip unnecessary calculations
  if(a.size === b.size) {
    return 0;
  }
  // literal comparison: SHORT < REG < LONG
  var aL = a.size.replace(/^[\s\d]+/, ''), bL = b.size.replace(/^[\s\d]+/, '');
  if((aL == 'SHORT' && bL != 'SHORT') || (aL == 'REG' && bL == 'LONG')) {
    return -1;
  }
  if((aL == 'REG' && bL == 'SHORT') || (aL == 'LONG' && bL != 'LONG')) {
    return 1;
  }
  // numeric comparison: 38 < 40 < 44 etc
  var aN = parseInt(a.size, 10), bN = parseInt(b.size, 10);
  if (aN < bN) {
    return -1;
  }
  if (aN > bN) {
    return 1;
  }
  return 0;
}

console.log(data.sort(compare));
```